# Convert a JSON object to PDF table in Node.JS without creating an HTML

Tags: json, node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, export-to-pdf

I am trying to integrate export to CSV and PDF functionality in my application.

I have done export to CSV using `json2csv` library, but I am having issues with PDF export.

What I would like is to export a JSON object I have in my `node.js` code to a PDF in tabular format, while using the array object keys(which will be same in all objects in the array) as the column headers.

Most of the resources I read online suggest creating a HTML template for export.
However, I want to keep my functionality generic, so that I can export any array of objects, no matter the number of keys(columns) in the objects of the array, so the static HTML template idea is, apparently, not suitable for my needs

ALSO, I would like the ability to make the PDF in Landscape mode and not in portrait mode.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

install npm

```
npm i html-pdf --save
```

add in your file

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
```

manage your data in table

```
table += "<table border='1' style='width:100%;word-break:break-word;'>";
table += "<tr>";
table += "<th >Column_Name</th>";
table += "<th >Column_Name";
table += "</tr>";

array.forEach(function(row){
    table += "<tr>";
    table += "<td>"+row.key_one+"</td>";
    table += "<td>"+row.key_tow+"</td>";
    table += "</tr>";
});
table += "</table>";
```

define pdf option

```
var options = {
  "format": "A4",
  "orientation": "landscape",
  "border": {
    "top": "0.1in",
},
"timeout": "120000"
};
```

create pdf file

```
pdf.create(table, options).toFile('save_file_path/test.pdf', function(err, result) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log("pdf create");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a good approach to keep your PDF layout independent of your data and HTML presentation - typically they should be different and fit for purpose.  This means you need to send your JSON as data into a PDF creation process.  To that end you will have the broadest options if you can include your server side as generation options (and I can't suggest any javascript PDF tools that don't go via HTML conversion).

This means with your JSON data on the server, calling the PDF creation process.  Depending on your server platform you can use a variety of PDF tools that are either tied to the platform language (eg Java/PHP) or a web service API which is language agnostic.  If you mention what your server options are I can probably make some suggestions.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using Node.JS 6.10.0 on AWS Lambda

Comment: But the thing is, for 10 listings, I dont want to create 10 different templates

Comment: Certainly you need at least 2 templates (portrait and landscape).  I don't know enough about Node.JS on AWS to broad options.  The only thing that occurs to me that might fit is to make a Web Service (http post / rest call) to a service like Docmosis (please note that I work for Docmosis).  A Docmosis template can support stripping columns from a table and/or choosing different tables based on the number of columns, but it cannot "grow" horizontally.  I don't have any better suggestions at this time.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of converting to html and then generating pdf. You can directly generate pdf using "pdfmake". I've used it and its very good library.
See this: https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/